# Get image from filesystem in PHP

Tags: php, image, file-io

I'm writing a PHP program that will get an image from the filesystem and display it on the returned page. The catch is that the file isn't stored in the /var/www directory. It's stored in /var/site/images. How can I do this? Do I have to read it into memory with fopen, then echo the contents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fpassthru` to dump the contents from the file system to the output stream. In fact the docs for `fpassthru` contains a demo of exactly what you're trying to do: https://www.php.net/fpassthru

```
<?php

// open the file in a binary mode
$name = './img/ok.png';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
// - adjust Content-Type as needed (read last 4 chars of file name)
// -- image/jpeg - jpg
// -- image/png - png
// -- etc.
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need to be able to include this as part of a larger HTML page I'm echoing in PHP. Sorry if I'm missing the obvious, but I'm a newb to PHP ;)

Comment: You need to refer to a PHP script like the one above via your `img` tag: `<img src="image.php?path=/var/www/foo.png" />` - this opens up security concerns, but logistically this is what you want to do. So really the `image.php` script is standalone and you feed it a query parameter telling it what image to render. But you should do lots of input sanitization to check the file is valid, etc.

Comment: @kewltek: Then what you need to do is use the php file Cody's code is in as the reference in your `src` on the `img` tag.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll work with this until I finish, then go back and address security issues. Thanks again. EDIT: I'll look into data URIs.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan The solution to that is to only allow, say `foo.png` which internally will show `/var/www/foo.png`.

Comment: @kewltek Don't forget the `fclose`. It isn't really needed, but it is still safe to do. Also, you should adjust the Content-Type as per the image: most old browsers (especially IE) don't use the magic of the data, but instead the Content-Type. On modern browsers, the base of `image/` tells the browser that this will be an image and then it will parse it based on its magic.